# how to write this if else condition statement in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement, image-processing

```
for each pixel, do
      if R>90 & R>G & R>B 
         classify the pixel as **Healthy**
      else 
         classify the pixel as non-healthy
```

I am trying to implement an algorithm which reads a skin lesion image and after extracting the R, G, and B values, it classifies the lesion into healthy skin or non-healthy skin based on the **if condition**

However, when I try to implement it, only the non-healthy skin array is getting updated inside the for loop and the healthy skin array remains zero. I do not know how to overcome this glitch. Please help.

```
hs=zeros(m,n); %initialising healthy skin array
nhs=0;         %initialising non-healthy skin array 
R=colorSkin(:, :, 1);
G=colorSkin(:, :, 2);
B=colorSkin(:, :, 3);
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n     
        if R>90&R>B&R>G
            hs(i, j)= colorSkin(i, j);
        else
            nhs(i,j)=colorSkin(i,j);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: There is no need to loop. You can write `result = R>90 & R>G & R>B ;` so in the result image healthy skin is `true` and non-healthy skin is `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, vectorized approach:

```
R=colorSkin(:, :, 1);
G=colorSkin(:, :, 2);
B=colorSkin(:, :, 3);
skin=repmat(R>90 & R>B & R>G,1,1,3);

hs=colorSkin;
hs(~skin)=0;
nhs(skin)=0;
```

This code should be considerably faster than looping

Answer (score 1):

When you running the loop, you are just checking the same matrix every time.

Here `R`, `G`, `B` all are a 2-D matrix.

I think you want to do the checking for each pixel's R, G, and B values.

So, when you did

`if R > 90 & R > B & R > G`

What it is doing is checking that **all** the elements of the `R` matrix are `> 90`, which may not be true for most of the time.

So the correct implementation is:

`if R(i, j) > 90 & R(i, j) > G(i, j) & R(i, j) > B(i, j)`

Change this code, and it should work fine. Please do comment if you want any further clarification.

Comment: This is working! But there is a small error. I am using a color image of size 447x700x3double. My R,G,B channels are all 384x512 double. 

 So when I run the for loop, I get an error saying:
Attempted to access R(1,513); index out of bounds because size(R)=[384,512].

The non-healthy skin array is getting updated correctly but the healthy skin array isn't.

Comment: @AnastasiaSakshmi initialize `nhs` the same way you do for `hs` or use the code in the other answer to solve your problem

Comment: Got it! Thank you. But I am unable to proceed further. I have to classify the non-healthy skin pixels into blue-veil or non-veil arrayus using the following algorithm:

for each pixel in extracted region do
   if R > 90 and R > B and R > G then
      Mark the pixel as healthy skin.
   else
     Ignore the pixel and continue.
end if
end for
Set R¯s as the mean of red channel values for pixels marked
healthy skin.
for each pixel in the image do
 nB = B/R+G+B
r R = R/R¯s
  if nB ≥ 0.3 and −194 ≤ rR < −51 then
Classify pixel as veil
else
Classify pixel as non-veil
end if
end for

Comment: I have updated the algorithm above in my question. Please look at it and guide me on how to continue after classifying the ROI into healthy and non-healthy skin. Thank you! @Ander Biguri @

Comment: @AnastasiaSakshmi if you have a new question, ask a new question, dont change this one