# How to write an if-else condition statement for the following algorithm in MATLAB?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

**ALGORITHM FOR BLUE-WHITE VEIL DETECTION**

```
**for** each pixel in extracted region do
      **if** R > 90 and R > B and R > G then
        Mark the pixel as **healthy skin**.
      **else**
        Ignore the pixel and continue.
    **end if
    end for**
    Set R¯s as the mean of red channel values for pixels marked
    healthy skin.
    **for** each pixel in the image **do**
      nB = B/R+G+B
      rR = R/R¯s
        **if** nB ≥ 0.3 and −194 ≤ rR < −51 then
          Classify pixel as veil
        **else**
          Classify pixel as non-veil
    **end if
    end for**
```

I have executed the first part of the algorith i.e. classifying the pixels into healthy skin or non-healthy skin. How to procced with the second part?

```
clc;
clear all; 
colorSkin=imread('veil.jpg'); %original image
% colorSkin=imresize(a, [384 512]);
[m, n]=size(colorSkin);
 hs = colorSkin; %initialising heaklthy skin array
 nhs = colorSkin; %initialising non-healthy skin array
 R = colorSkin(:, :, 1);
 G = colorSkin(:, :, 2);
 B = colorSkin(:, :, 3);
 ROI = R > 95 & R > B & R > G;
 ROI3 = ROI(:,:,[1 1 1]);
 hs(~ROI3) = 0;
 nhs(ROI3) = 0;
```

When I try to implement the second part of the algorithm using the command below:

```
> nB=B(hs)./(R(hs)+B(hs)+G(hs));
```

I get an error that says **"Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."**

Comment: You need to. 1) learn MATLAB. 2) reference previous answers. That is my code from an answer that you did not even accept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract the blue-veil feature from skin images in using MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352564/how-to-extract-the-blue-veil-feature-from-skin-images-in-using-matlab)

Comment: Please, we require a minimum quality of effort by you. Read [ask]

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm new to MATLAB as well as stackoverflow. I shall read "How to ask" before I post the next time. Thank you for your patience and help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your algorithm,You need the RBG of **all** data, not just the healthy skin, at least the way you write it it definitely seems so. Else, `rR` would make no sense. Additionally realize that your pseudo-code **must** be wrong, because it is impossible for `rR` to be negative.

[Continuing from my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358746/how-to-write-this-if-else-condition-statement-in-matlab)

```
R=colorSkin(:, :, 1);
G=colorSkin(:, :, 2);
B=colorSkin(:, :, 3);
skin=repmat(R>90 & R>B & R>G,1,1,3);

hs=colorSkin;
hs(~skin)=0;
nhs(skin)=0;

% new code
nB = B./(R+G+B); % I assume you dont mean B./R+G+B as in the pseudocode....
rR=R./mean(R(skin(:,:,1)>0);

% use the same code as before, changing the indexes to classify veil
```